# How to pass an API app key as a prop in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, restful-url, vue-cli, vue-props

I need to pass the api app key as a prop in order to dynamically change it instead of hard-coding the key in. The code provided will present the issue in better detail.

App.vue:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
import Api from './Api.js'

export default {
  name: 'Widget',
  components: {
    someComponent
  },
  props: {
    albumName: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Homepage'
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      .....
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData () {
      const options = {
        'album_name': this.$props.albumName
      }

      const { images, pagination } = await Api.getData(options)
      this.media = this.media.concat(images)
      this.morePagesAvailable = (pagination.page * pagination.per_page) < pagination.total
    },
  .....
</script>
```

Api.js

```
import 'whatwg-fetch'
import queryString from 'query-string'

const APP_KEY = '1s4...dzqvux'

const getData = async (options) => {
  const params = queryString.stringify({
    ...options
  })

  const response = await window.fetch(`https://someURL/${APP_KEY}/theAlbumParameters?${params}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  })

  return response.json()
}

Api = {
  async getData (options) {
    const data = await getData(options)
    return data.response
  }
}

export default Api
```

I would like to have the "APP_KEY" as a prop instead of hard-coded just like the "album_name" that is passed as a prop from Api.js to App.vue. Please let me know with any other information I can provide. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use process.env for storing your API keys and settings variables. Store your key like this where you create your vue instance or where your vue start point. Example

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  APP_KEY: '"blablakey"'
}
```

then everywhere in your vue.js app you can access

```
console.log(process.env.APP_KEY);
```

See more info [in documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html).

Comment: However, I'd like to pass it as a prop in app.vue

Comment: Ok, then make it prop, what's your problem, where are you stuck, please provide more info